# Weak dependence of MA

Tags: covariance, time-series

So I have this MA : $x_t$ = $e_t$ + A$e_{t-1}$
How do I compute covariance between $x_t$ and $x_{t+1}$?

I'm completely missing the intuition here as my book just states the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\renewcommand\cov{\operatorname{Cov}}$ 
First, by defintion of covariance, 
$$\cov(X_t,X_{t+1}) = E[X_tX_{t+1}] - E[X_t]E[X_{t+1}].$$
For an $\operatorname{MA}$ process, process $\{e_t\}$ is a white noise process so $E[e_t] = 0$ for all $t$.

Then use that 
$X_{t+1} = e_{t+1} + Ae_{t}$
so
\begin{align*}
E[X_tX_{t+1}] 
&= 
E[(e_t + Ae_{t-1})(e_{t+1} + Ae_t)]
\\&= 
E[e_te_{t+1}] + AE[e_t^2] + AE[e_{t-1}e_{t+1}] + A^2E[e_{t-1}e_t].
\end{align*}

From the definition of a white noise process, $E[e_te_s] = 0 $ for $t\neq s$. Thus,
$$
E[X_tX_{t+1}] = 0+AE[e_t^2] + 0+0 = AE[e_t^2].
$$